# Adding null conditional to function throw not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m new with Angular and JS and I have a funcion that load a simple select like this:

**Angular Ctrl**

```
function detalleRegistrosCtrl($scope, apiService, notificationService, $rootScope, $location, $stateParams, $http, $state) {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        $scope.catalogoPadre = $stateParams.catalogopadre;

        cargarCatalogo();


    $scope.regresar = function () {
        $state.go("root.catalogosgenericos");
    }


    function errorCatalogo(res) {
        bootbox.alert("Error al cargar el catalogo" + res.data);
    }

     function cargarCatalogo() {
         apiService.get("../../api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoPadre/" + $scope.Catalogo + "/", null,
            function (res) {

                $scope.Catalogos = res.data;
                $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;
            }, errorCatalogo);
```

Problem is when I try to add an if conditional into cargarCatalogo() function. When I do it as:

```
    if ($scope.catalogoPadre != null) {

     function cargarCatalogo() {
         apiService.get("../../api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoPadre/" + $scope.Catalogo + "/", null,
            function (res) {
                $scope.Catalogos = res.data;
                $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;
            }, errorCatalogo);
     }
```

I´m getting into chrome console:

> Error: cargarCatalogo is not defined

Can someone explain me what is wrong? I just add a conditional to a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of wrapping condition on the function declaration , add the condition when you call the `cargarCatalogo()` function. On your `detalleRegistrosCtrl` already calling that function

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$scope.catalogoPadre = $stateParams.catalogopadre;
if ($scope.catalogoPadre != null) {
    cargarCatalogo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple because `cargarCatalogo()` is defined inside an `if` statement.

You will have to define it outside `if`.

And then while using it wrap it the function call in `if` statement.

If you define it inside `if` it will never get defined until you run the code and the if statement is executed. Hence it will throw error.

Comment: Actually `cargarCatalogo();`  invoked method is outside my if statement,   `function cargarCatalogo() {` is inside if, I dont found any issues there

Comment: Answer is right, because your function definition itself is inside `if` , which is not executed yet, but you have called it even before that. In first case where your function is outside `if` , your controller knows that there is method with that name.